# Is there an easy way to substitute XML like tags with specific hex values with Python3?

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x

I have a set of data that is structured like XML but the data is NOT ascii but instead hex.

For instance, the data could be

```
EX. A
<body>
    <entry1> 0x12 </entry1>
    <entry2> 0x01 </entry2>
</body>
```

and that could translate to

```
EX. B
<0x01>
    <0x02> 0x12 <0xff>
    <0x03> 0x01 <0xff>
<0xff>
```

In the example above (EX B), `<0x02> 0x12 <0xff>` indicates that entry1 has a value of 0x12.

I am not a native python programmer, so I may be going about doing this the long way (would love it if it were easier) but what I am trying to do is go from the human readable structure (EX. A) to the hex version (EX B).

My idea is to write the XML like to file using lxml and populating the neccessary revelent area,  and read the file with Python and perform  substitutions using string manipulation for the tags based off a code book/ dictionary.

In the end, I am looking for a byte array that would look like

```
0x01 0x02 0x12 0xff 0x03 0x01 0xff 0xff
```

My question is : Is there an easier way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A custom `html.HTMLParser` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html)) might suit your needs:

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.__tags = {}
        self.__counter = 1

        self.__result = []

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if not tag in self.__tags:
            self.__tags[tag] = '0x{:02x}'.format(self.__counter)
            self.__counter += 1
        self.__result.append(self.__tags[tag])

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        self.__result.append('0xff')

    def handle_data(self, data):
        self.__result.append(data.strip())

    @property
    def result(self):
        return [v for v in self.__result if v]

parser = MyHTMLParser()
parser.feed('''<body>
    <entry1> 0x12 </entry1>
    <entry2> 0x01 </entry2>
</body>''')

print(' '.join(parser.result))
```

Prints:

```
0x01 0x02 0x12 0xff 0x03 0x01 0xff 0xff
```

Comment: This is great! There alot of stuff in here for me to dissect and understand more in detail.